# Apache rewrite rule for error page in httpd.conf

Tags: httpd.conf

I have to write a rewrite rule inside the httpd.conf for showing error code if the User-Agent is Mozilla firefox. I tried this rule

```
<VirtualHost *:8004>
SSLEngine on
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond "{HTTPD_USER_AGENT}" "^Mozilla/5.*"
RewriteRule ^/?page\.html$ - [R=404]
</VirtualHost>
```

I can able to restart the apache, but not showing an error page when accessing through firefox.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what error you get during your tests but try something like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

And if you want a customized 404 page, configure a proper ErrorDocument

```
ErrorDocument 404 /var/www/ErrorPages/404.php
```